# Crystal Report Prompt Text Disappears After Datasource Location Switch

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My company is using Crystal Reports 2008 for basic reporting needs and right now we currently keep 2 different test servers.

I made a report from a stored procedure on Server1 with the parameters all labeled and set prompt text exactly how I wanted it. When we needed to change it to point to Server2's SP instance (via Set Datasource Location), I changed it but when I saved the report all of the parameter text dropped off.

Usually I wouldn't ask this, but these stored procs have over 50 parameter fields (customized with hard-coded dropdowns) so starting from a blank one for each of these would be painful.

Has this happened to anyone? Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere that may clear the prompts on save?

Any help is much appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps

Change the command again.

Log off then login to the DB.

Verify the DB.